# What do you call a woman who ululates?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests, agent-nouns

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ululation) explains:

> Ululation is a long, wavering, high-pitched vocal sound resembling a howl with a trilling quality. It is produced by emitting a high pitched loud voice accompanied with a rapid back and forth movement of the tongue and the uvula.
>
> Ululation is practiced either alone or as part of certain styles of singing, on various occasions of communal ritual events (like weddings) used to express strong emotion.

**What do you call the woman who does this?**

Comment: There is an internet blogger who goes by the moniker, **ululationist**.

Comment: I think it is used mainly in sorrowful contexts: **Ululation** is often mournful and it's always full of emotion. It's a common cultural reaction to a death, as well as a highly expressive way of grieving. In some cases, ululation can be celebratory or joyful rather than sad. It's been used to mean "wailing" since the 16th century, and its origin traces back to the Latin word with that same meaning, ululationem.*

Comment: I don't think there's a good single word for this in English. 'Women who ululate' would be the way to say it. Is there a single word for this concept in your native language?

Comment: That suggests *mourner*, perhaps. If they're Jewish weddings, there is a special word for it, which I will go search for now ...

Comment: Too late to edit my comment, >.<
 It appears the *trilling* form you mention is usually associated with celebration, rather, in the Arabic world. Do you have a bit more cultural context?

Comment: Are you referring specifically to a zaghareet?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to zaghareet. But I would go for ululators too. What would you go with?

Answer (score 2):

As with any active verb in English, you can form an agent noun simply by adding *-er* to the stem:

> Had she been of different ethnic stock, what a keener or an *ululater* she'd have been. As it was, she sang old Methodist hymns about walking with Jesus, and came out with unexpected words like glory- osky and infidel.   [—Roy Blount, Jr. *Alphabet Juice,* 2009.](https://books.google.de/books?id=xZWKctOqg8YC&pg=PT431&lpg=PT431&dq=ululater&source=bl&ots=gKlFXZlNLx&sig=8HGNtN5qWDRbaFAHW_nOS5BnvjU&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihkZnMkLrZAhVLhywKHf_xAjE4ChDoATAAegQICRAB)

This doesn't mean, of course, that you have to. *A group of ululating women* sounds much better than *a group of ululaters*.

Comment: I think I would go for *ululator,* though.

Comment: And not a ululatrice? :)

Comment: @KarlG My immediate thought was _ululatrix_, which I shall henceforth endeavour to promote to common usage.

Comment: Using female-specific forms is commonly considered sexist these days. Although there may be cultural reasons why only women ululate in certain contexts

Comment: _Any_  [dynamic?] verb? Acter? Raper?